# What is the difference between locate txt vs locate *.txt?

Tags: shell, filenames, locate

Output of `locate txt | head`:

```
/etc/brltty/brl-ba-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-bd-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-bl-18.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-bl-40_m20_m40.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-ec-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-ec-spanish.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-eu-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-lb-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-lt-all.txt
/etc/brltty/brl-mb-all.txt
```

Output of `locate *.txt | head`:

```
/home/abc/capital.txt
/home/abc/state.txt
```

Why is there such a huge difference in the output?
The second command only seems to check my home folder, but the first command seems to check many directories. Why is that the case?

Answer (score 23):

`locate txt` locates all files (of any type including regular, symlink, directory, socket...)  whose path contains `txt`¹, so includes `/foo/xtxty/bar`, `/foo/bar.txt`, `/foo/txt.bar`, etc.

`locate *.txt` is wrong because that `*` is left unquoted, so the `*.txt` would be expanded by the shell to all the filenames in the current directory matching that pattern first and the result passed to `locate`, so for instance, if the current directory contained `a.txt` and `b.txt`, that would end up running `locate a.txt b.txt` which locates paths that contain either  `a.txt` and `b.txt` or depending on the `locate` implementation, both of them such as `/foo/da.txtob.txt` (yours looking like it's one in the first category and you likely ran the command from within `/home/abc`).

If there's no `.txt` file in the current directory, depending on the shell you get either an error or `locate` is called with `*.txt` literally  as argument.

To always call `locate` with a literal `*.txt` which is what you want here, you want to make sure that `*` is quoted for the shell, either with `"..."`, `'...'` or backslash if in a Bourne-like shell, single quotes being the best as they quote every character in Bourne-like shell and are the most portable among shells:

```
locate '*.txt'
```

Then, as that argument contains a wildcard (`*`), `locate` switches from a subtstring search to a pattern matching search (same ones as those recognised by the shell or `find -name` for instance) and returns all the file paths that match that pattern, that is, all the file paths that end in `.txt`, like `/foo/.txt` or `/foo/bar.txt`.

`locate` is not a standard command, and there are many incompatible implementations around, but those simple behaviours above are common to most if not all. Most implementations support various options to do the matching differently. Check your own `locate` documentation with `man locate`, not some random pages on the internet as they may very  well document a different implementation and/or version.

---

<sup>¹ and that did exist at the time the locate database was last updated</sup>

Answer (score 8):

When you use globbing like that (`<command> *.txt`) for instance, the expansion is done by your shell, not the command you're running, or in this case `locate`.

If you want to ensure the globbing character gets passed on to the command you're running, put it in quotes:

```
locate "*.txt"
```

or escape it with `\`:

```
locate \*.txt
```

---

Furthermore, `locate` has a matching algorithm more or less based on regexp, but not quite.
If searching for `txt`, it'll assume you want `txt` to be part of the filename, not necessarily at the end.

You *can* force regexp handling though:

```
locate -r "txt$"
```

For further details, refer to the [`locate` man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/locate)

Answer (score 5):

`locate` takes *patterns* as arguments. Since `*.txt` is not quoted, the shell tries to expand it first instead of passing it literally.

Also, note:

> As a special case, a pattern containing no globbing characters (``foo'')
> is matched as though it were ``*foo*''.

So `locate txt` is equivalent to `locate '*txt*'`. Assuming the current directory only contains `a.txt` and `b.txt`, then `locate *.txt` expands to `locate a.txt b.txt`, and so is equivalent to `locate '*a.txt*' '*b.txt*'`.